# "Far above" vs "Well above"

Tags: word-usage, phrase-usage, phrase-choice

Are "well above" and "far above" interchangeable? I know that we can use "well" when talking about something that is above another thing. Can we use, "far" instead of "well". I have seen examples of "well above" in sentences about a "limit" but I wonder about a situation when something is physically above something in space. For example, can we say these sentences:

- The bridge is far above the road.
- The birds are far above the hikers.
- The plane flew far above us.

etc. As I said, I have seen "far above" being used in dictionaries when talking about a limit like in "Far above temperature 0". I wonder if we can use it when talking about something is over something in real space. I would like to know if we can use "far below" the same way as well.

Comment: 'Far above' means  'a long way above', but 'well above' can just mean 'appreciably above' in a relative sense. A plane in the sky is far above my head, but I can say that $105 is well above my budget for this week, if I only have $100.

Answer (score 0):

You can use “far above” to describe physical space.

> The mountain towered far above us

The usage is, however, a bit literary. More common would be

> The mountain towered high above us.

In other words, “high” is the basic word to indicate a large distance upward, just as “deep” indicates a large vertical distance downward, but “far” can be used as well.

Comment: You can also use "way" as a more general term.

Comment: "way above" is a bit colloquial. I don't think "far above" is literary - it's not very colloquial but would be in place e.g. in a news broadcast or informal business memo/email.

Answer (score 0):

More or less wherever you can use "well above" you can used "far above"; though it is possible that "far above" is perhaps a *little* stronger than "well above".  Also, as I explain below, the right choice of expression will provide nuance to your utterance.

For example, "well above" suggests that something is far enough above another thing *for a particular purpose*:

"The top of the greenhouse is well above the expected maximum height of the egg plants we intend to grow in it." ...

... but later ...

"The egg plants have grown far above our expectations."

Please note that we could use "far" in the first sentence and "well" in the second, but we'd be less likely to do either, and we'd lose a little nuance from the sentence if we did.

Lastly, "we'd be more likely to use "far" for larger distances and "well" for smaller ones:

"The stars are far above us." sounds better than "The stars are well above us.

but

"The grass has now grown well above the height of the clover." is probably better than "The grass has grown far above ..."

And

"The surface of the water is well below the lip of the beaker."

but

"Captain Nemo's submarine is far below the surface of the ocean."

Answer (score 0):

Far above is a little more exaggerated than well above, while far above usually means
a long way above, but usually still quite clear to the human eye, while well above means a little above mid-air.

Comment: This doesn't really add anything new, and is also not really true. (Just for the record: I'm not stalking you, I just happen to go through review queues on this site and on Arqade earlier :) To stop me from harassing you, please take the [Tour] on all of the sites you want to participate in, and carefully read how this platform, and the specific sites, work. Welcome to Stack Exchange!)